# How do I add a new page to my contents

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco for the 1st time with VS2017.

I have been following this great tutorial: [Tutorial - How to create a Contact Form in Umbraco using MVC and C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3V0A1AYJbys)

I have created the controller, partial view and model.

The last bit was to add this to the contents in the Umbraco admin portal.

That link showed how to replace the existing 'Contact' page.

But, I am trying to add as a new page.

To ensure this I deleted the existing Contact page before I started this tutorial.

This is my Template List (note Contact Template that I have created)

[image]

This is the Document Type (note that its Template is pointing to my Contact Template)

[image]

Now this is the list of my available Templates I can add to my Content Tree:

[image]

I want to create a new item of Product Type Contact.

But it is not listed.

Obviously, I am doing some howler here.

Can anyone educate me please?

Thanks

ADDITIONAL

I have followed @ayo's suiggestion.

I go to Home in Document Types + Click On Templates and Browse and add the Contact Page:

[image]

But this Contact page is showing the default contact page I had already deleted and not my new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is tell Umbraco that your new document type should be allowed to be created under Home Document type.

You need to go to settings, expand Document Types and select Home. Then you need to click on Permissions (top right, next to Templates) and select the Contact document type on the Allowed Child Node Types property. This should allow you to create Contact pages beneath the Home page.

Comment: Thanks. This still did not give me what I wanted.  It was easier to add to my question. Please refer to that :) thanks

Comment: click on choose extra templates, then you will get a list of all the templates, then add your one.

Comment: I have gone to settings.I have expanded Document Types. I have selected Home. I have clicked 'Choose extra Templates'. I have chosen my contact page. I have clicked on the Content Button. I have gone to the 3 dots against Home. It does not show. Nor does it appear in the list underneath 'Products, People, About Us, Blog'?

Comment: This is incorrect. You need to go to settings, expand Document Types and select Home. Then you need to click on Permissions (top right, next to Templates) and select the Contact document type on the Allowed Child Node Types property. This should allow you to create Contact pages beneath the Home page.